# Passing `this` to child object

Tags: c++, c++17

Is this method of passing and storing `this` to a child object still considered 'acceptable' when using `C++17`, or is there a more appropriate method, in line with the language and standard?

I am specifically asking regarding passing and storing the `Parent` object as a plain pointer.

```
class Child
{
public:
    void SetParent(Parent* p)
    {
        _parent = p;
    }
private:
    Parent* _parent;
};

class Parent
{
public:
    void MyMethod()
    {
        Child c;
        c.SetParent(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: `c.SetParent(this)` - why don't you provide the parent in the constructor instead?

Comment: the problem is always dangling pointers, you may pass a weak_ptr, but you need much more rework. If you are sure of the lifetime, you may use a reference on father at child creation.

Comment: Not in general, but here you have a circular dependency, which is always not a good technique and your child in MyMethod dies immediately after the function call. If this is intended, it is ok. But you should guarantee to remove the "parent" if the parent dies.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It could be passed in the constructor. My question is more to do with passing and storing the `Parent` object as a plain pointer.

Comment: In c++ ≥ 11, the preferred method is to use smart pointers... You'll have to think about who owns who to decide which smart pointer to use. In general, prefer not to use raw pointers, they are considered too dangerous. But if you really, need/want, then your way is almost correct, why don't you think so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post-C++11 you can use `std::weak_ptr<Parent>`, assuming you're using `std::shared_ptr<Parent>` (and inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this` in order to generate a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::weak_ptr` internally).

Aside from that, yes, it's still acceptable to use a raw pointer to represent lack of ownership or back pointer (until the committee adds some kind of `std::owned_ptr<T>` / `std::ptr_view<T>` class).